# Webcomponents v1 - Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

trying out webcomponents but have gotten to a error I dont get.

The markup is simple and should work. 2 files, both are html files.

the error is marked on the `<script>` tag on in the console.

Thanks for any assistance.

*PS. I am running Google Chrome Beta to get the customElements to work.*

**km-button.html**

```
<script>

class KmButton extends HTMLButtonElement {

   constructor() {
     super();
   }

}

customElements.define('km-button', KmButton, {extends: 'button'});

</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--  import webcomponents  -->
        <link rel="import" href="./components/km-button.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <km-button>hej</km-button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
km-button.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor(…)KmButton @ km-button.html:7
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually it still does't work (after your corrections).

AFAIK the `extends` feature is not implemented yet in Custom Elements v1 for Chrome.

So the `is=` syntax is simply (and silently) ignored and your button is viewed as a standard `<button>`.

Comment: hmm ok just figured it worked as it no longer gave a error, ended up not using the **is=** syntax as it seems Apple will not implement it in Webkit. But thanks for letting me know.

Comment: A workaround is to use this polyfill: https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element

Comment: thank you for the link, but I do not think that adding a polyfill while in development is a good practice and that they should only be used when doing the buildtask for the end-user at the "End".

Comment: If you say so :) Don't know how to reply to that. But this is not a place to argue so I just let it be.

Comment: i meant using *this* library to develop custom elements (v1) and anticipate its future browser implementation is not a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yea seems I was mistaken with the `<km-button></km-button>` tag it's supposed to be `<button is="km-button">some text</button>` when you are extending another DOM element.

Leaving the question up if anyone runs in the the same mistake.